# Pandas Read HTML wont scrape the clickable image

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For reference I am scraping this website: https://apps.proni.gov.uk/Val12B/SearchResults.aspx

The table looked like this:
[image]

I am trying to scrape this table along with the clickable links on the PRONI REFERENCE header.

my code is:

`table_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//table[@id='gvSearchResults']")`

```
for i in table_elements:
    a = pd.read_html(i.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
    dfs.append(a[0])
```

but the dataframe looks like:
[image]

my next plan to to individually scrape the href, collect it as a list and join it to the previous dataframe, unfortunately upon inspecting the elements, the table elements containing the link does not have an href.

[image]

The ideal dataframe should contain the clickable link which will be saved as an excel file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the image link is anywhere on the page. Clicking the "hyperlink" takes you to a page where you can view hundreds of images one-by-one, but the link in the address bar is the same for all rows - the pages on this site all seem to be rendered after a series of requests and redirects, so a simple link will not suffice. Even a link like https://apps.proni.gov.uk/Val12B/RelatedVolume.aspx?6139 will be redirected to the search page unless you click from one of their pages first [try opening in incognito mode from here and you might notice].

I think, at best, you can code to click on each link and get the image url of the first, index and last images (and a fixed number of extra images, if you want, but each image is an extra click, an extra set of requests...), and add a column for each image_url. Obviously that will be considerably slower than your current method because of having to click so many things, and probably the waits as well if they don't load immediately.

Skeleton code:

```py
prefVals = [
    e.get_attribute('value') for e in 
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//table[@id='gvSearchResults']//td/input")
]
val_scraped = []
max_scrapes = len(table_elements) # or whatever you prefer

valImgs = []

for i in range(max_scrapes):
    prefs = [
        e for e in 
        driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//table[@id='gvSearchResults']//td/input")
        if e.get_attribute('value') not in val_scraped
    ]
    if not prefs: break # all scraped

    val_i = prefs[0].get_attribute('value')
    prefs[0].click()
    # add wait if necessary

    first_image = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//img[@id="ImgCtrlLarge"]').get_attribute('src')

    # click for more images if you want

    val_scraped.append(val_i)
    valImgs.append([val_i, first_image, ...]) # add all image links for val_i

    # use "< Search Results" button to go back
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//input[@id="backButton"]').click()
    # add wait if necessary

imgCols = [[r for r in valImgs if r[0] == v] for v in prefVals]
imgCols = [r[0] if len(r) > 0 else [] for r in imgCols]
imgCol_headers = ['PRONI_REFERENCE_VALUE', 'FIRST_IMAGE', ....] # add in headers as appropriate

imgDfs = pd.DataFrame(imgCols, columns=imgCol_headers)

finalDf = pd.concat([dfs[0], imgDfs], axis=1)
```